# Solution to the cototient function equation

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

I would like to know what are the exact solutions for the equation $x-\phi(x)  = k$, where $\phi$ is the totient function and $k$ is equal to $167$, a highly cototient number.

I was told there are $15$ solutions to this equation. Any advice on these solution or how to solve this problem in MapleSoft or using Python?
Thanks.

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Mathematica program takes a second or two to produce the output below.

---

$\text{Block}[\{x=1,n=1,\text{outList}=\{\}\},\text{While}[n\leq 15,\text{If}[x-\phi (x)=167,\text{outList}=\text{AppendTo}[\text{outList},\{n,x\}];n\text{++}];x\text{++}];\text{Grid}[\text{outList}]]$

---

$\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 455 \\
 2 & 815 \\
 3 & 1727 \\
 4 & 2567 \\
 5 & 2831 \\
 6 & 4031 \\
 7 & 4247 \\
 8 & 4847 \\
 9 & 5207 \\
 10 & 6431 \\
 11 & 6527 \\
 12 & 6767 \\
 13 & 6887 \\
 14 & 7031 \\
 15 & 27889 \\
\end{array}$

---

Recalling $\phi(x)=x\prod\limits_{p|x}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$, the following Mathematica program and subsequent output perhaps provides a bit more insight.

---

$\text{Block}\left[\left\{n=1,x=1,\text{outList}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{n} & \text{x} & \text{xFactors} & \text{yList} & \text{x Product[m,$\{$m,yList$\}$]} & \text{x-167} \\
\end{array}
\right),\text{xFactors},\text{yList}=\{\}\right\},\text{While}\left[n\leq 15,\text{If}\left[x-\phi (x)=167,\text{xFactors}=\text{FactorInteger}[x];\text{yList}=1-\frac{1}{\text{First}\text{/@}\text{FactorInteger}[x]};\text{outList}=\text{AppendTo}\left[\text{outList},\left\{n,x,\text{xFactors},\text{yList},x \prod _m^{\text{yList}} m,x-167\right\}\right];n\text{++}\right];x\text{++}\right];\text{Grid}[\text{outList}]\right]$

---

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{n} & \text{x} & \text{xFactors} & \text{yList} & \phi(x)=x\prod\limits_{m\in\text{yList}} m & \phi(x)=x-167 \\
 1 & 455 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 1 \\
 7 & 1 \\
 13 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{7},\frac{12}{13}\right\} & 288 & 288 \\
 2 & 815 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 1 \\
 163 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{4}{5},\frac{162}{163}\right\} & 648 & 648 \\
 3 & 1727 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 1 \\
 157 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{10}{11},\frac{156}{157}\right\} & 1560 & 1560 \\
 4 & 2567 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 17 & 1 \\
 151 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{16}{17},\frac{150}{151}\right\} & 2400 & 2400 \\
 5 & 2831 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 19 & 1 \\
 149 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{18}{19},\frac{148}{149}\right\} & 2664 & 2664 \\
 6 & 4031 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 29 & 1 \\
 139 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{28}{29},\frac{138}{139}\right\} & 3864 & 3864 \\
 7 & 4247 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 31 & 1 \\
 137 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{30}{31},\frac{136}{137}\right\} & 4080 & 4080 \\
 8 & 4847 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 37 & 1 \\
 131 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{36}{37},\frac{130}{131}\right\} & 4680 & 4680 \\
 9 & 5207 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 41 & 1 \\
 127 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{40}{41},\frac{126}{127}\right\} & 5040 & 5040 \\
 10 & 6431 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 59 & 1 \\
 109 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{58}{59},\frac{108}{109}\right\} & 6264 & 6264 \\
 11 & 6527 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 61 & 1 \\
 107 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{60}{61},\frac{106}{107}\right\} & 6360 & 6360 \\
 12 & 6767 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 67 & 1 \\
 101 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{66}{67},\frac{100}{101}\right\} & 6600 & 6600 \\
 13 & 6887 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 71 & 1 \\
 97 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{70}{71},\frac{96}{97}\right\} & 6720 & 6720 \\
 14 & 7031 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 79 & 1 \\
 89 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{78}{79},\frac{88}{89}\right\} & 6864 & 6864 \\
 15 & 27889 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 167 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left\{\frac{166}{167}\right\} & 27722 & 27722 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what i wanted.